# Problema na criação de entidade com relacionamento de um para um

Tags: java

Criei um projeto para realização de teste, e estou estudando a criação de entidade com relacionamentos, e nisso criei duas entidade com esse relacionamento abaixo:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Estou conseguindo criar as entidade, porém não da forma certa, utilizando essa classe abaixo:

```
package br.com.softplan.jpa;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;

import br.com.softplan.model.Pedido;

public class CadastraCategoriaJPA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pedido p = new Pedido();
        p.setNome_pedido("descrocao");

        EntityManager em = PersistenceUtil.getEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
        try {
            tx.begin();
            em.persist(p);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        PersistenceUtil.close(em);
        PersistenceUtil.close();
    }    
}
```

Quero saber como criar as entidade com os relacionamento colocando os valores dos atributos das duas tabelas.

Tabela "pedido":

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String nome_pedido;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "endereco_id")
private Endereco enderecoEntrega;
```

Tabela "endereço":

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long endereco_id;
private String lougradouro;
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "enderecoEntrega")
private Pedido pedido;
```

Essa foi uma tentativa mas não deu certo:

```
Pedido p = new Pedido();
Endereco end = new Endereco();

p.setNome_pedido("descrocao");

end.setLougradouro("hdsbcjhbsdjc");
end.setPedido(p);
```

Comment: Você citou que está estudando ainda mas apesar disso sugiro que utilize nos códigos as convenções de Java.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Comment: Acho que a Daniela deixou claro que o link não respondia a sua pergunta, é apenas uma sugestão de se usar as convenções que desenvolvedores Java utilizam para facilitar a comunicação entre os mesmos. E é uma boa sugestão, diria eu.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pedido p = new Pedido();
Endereco end = new Endereco();
end.setLogradouro("teste");
//set aqui o objeto completo do endereço
p.setEndereco(end);
```